# Aligning header site title and logo image

Tags: css

I am trying to get a specific format in the header for this website www.theflowerpotcmd.co

I want the text to sit on the left and the image to be on the right

I used

```css
p.site-title {
 float:left;
 padding-top:100px;
 font-size:80px;
}
.custom-logo{
 padding-top:20px;
 max-height:200px;
}
```

but the image keeps itself shifted to the right and not aligning next to the text

Also, I am trying to set the text to different sizes when it's tablet/mobile but Im not sure why my snippet of code isnt working

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .p.site-title {
 float:left;
 padding-top:100px;
 font-size:0px;
}
 }
```

this is a wordpress website/dara theme

Thank you for any help

Comment: When you say aligning to the text do you mean vertically aligning?

Comment: yes, I mean vertical align, sorry for vagueness